# Retrieving item from list

Tags: c#, list

I'm having some problems retrieving information from a list.

In this case I'd like to get the name from a list, eventually I want it turned into a string. This is what I have:

```
public string ShowName(int patientcode)
{
    List<ExtendPatientInfo> patientdata = dk.RetrieveList(patientcode);
    string name = patientdata. <What here?>
    return name;
}
```

In the class ExtendPatientInfo I have this, which I think is allright:

```
private string name;
public ExtendPatientInfo(string name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

I tried using a few things. Like Contains, Find, FindIndex and where. But none of these worked for me because I probably messed something up somewhere. Anybody that can help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to choose the patient. If it is all the same data for the patient, then you can use  LINQ's First

```
patientdata.First().Name
```

But, if they are all different, then you could map the list to only have Names

```
patientdata.Select(x=>x.Name)
```

At which point, you would still need to iterate through the list to display each name or whatever you need.

---

As Henk points out, if this is always going to be a list of one item, then you could use

```
patientdata.Single().Name
```

*The caveat with `Single` is from MSDN

> Returns the only element of a sequence, and throws an exception if there is not exactly one element in the sequence.

Comment: patientcode suggest uniqueness, and then `.Single()` would be better.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yah, I didnt go with that because I didnt want to assume uniqueness (you wouldnt need a list...) I will add it as a caveat though

Answer (score 3):

Well you have a list of object and you want to show properties of each object, then you have to access each object in the list and then access it properties. Something like:

```
foreach(var item in patientdata)
{
  Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
  //rest of the fields
}
```

If you want to select a single object from  your list then you cause use [First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) / [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) , [Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.single%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) / [SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) depending on your need. But you need an individual object to access it properties. You can't access a property directly from a list.

```
var item = patientData.FirstOrDefault();
if(item != null)
   Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
string name = string.Empty;
var pd = patientData.FirstOrDefault();
if(pd != null)
     name = pd.Name
```

This code gets the first item returned or null.
If it isn;t null it retrieves the Name property value into string variable name.

Incidentally, if you don;t want to learn linq right now you can access List<> via index like:

```
 patientData[0].Name
```

You will still want to check that patientData[0] is not null before checking the Name property.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx). Linq allows you to cycle through a list easily and get what you want.

For example, if you want the patient named "Johan":

```
ExtendPatientInfo patient = patientdata.Where(x => x.Name == "Johan").FirstOrDefault();
string name = patient.Name;
```

Comment: If the list comes back empty this code will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you are looking for something like this

```
ExtendPatientInfo patient = 
         patientdata.FirstOrDefault(x => x.patientcode == patientcode);

return 
    (patient != null)
        ? patient.Name
        : null
```