# Froma list of objects, How to get a list of a specific object parameter value base in another parameter value

Tags: c#, list, linq, lambda

Not sure I am doing something wrong. I have been looking on the internet how to efficiently get a list of property values, base in another property, using lambda.

Let's say I have a list of classrooms with the Teacher name and Room Id:

```
public class ClassRoom
{
    public string Teacher;
    public int RoomId;

}

List<ClassRoom> classRooms = new List<ClassRoom>();

classRooms.Add(new ClassRoom() { RoomId = 2000, Teacher = "Mr. Taylor" });
classRooms.Add(new ClassRoom() { RoomId = 2010, Teacher = "Mrs. Lee" });
classRooms.Add(new ClassRoom() { RoomId = 3050, Teacher = "Mrs. McNamara" });
classRooms.Add(new ClassRoom() { RoomId = 4090, Teacher = "Mr. Taylor" });
```

Then, I would need a list of room Ids for a specific teacher.

```
List<int> RoomIds = new List<int>();

    foreach(ClassRoom classRoom in classRooms)
    {
        if(classRoom.Teacher == "Mr.Taylor")
        {
            RoomIds.Add(classRoom.RoomId);
        }
    }
```

I am after a lambda expression or any other way that is efficient and compact to get a list of Room Ids. I always end up getting a list of the main class (ClassRoom).

I was after something like this:

```
List<int> RoomIds = classRooms.Where(x => x.Teacher == "Mr.Taylor").ToList();
```

I know the above expression is wrong as the operation gives me a List of ClassRoom and not the RoomIds I need. I just wanted to depict what I am after.

Is that even possible? I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving item from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341595/retrieving-item-from-list)

Answer (score 5):

You're missing a [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1):

```
List<int> RoomIds = classRooms
    .Where(x => x.Teacher == "Mr.Taylor")
    .Select(x => x.RoomId)
    .ToList();
```

If it's possible for two teachers to have the same `RoomId` and you want a unique list of room ids, you can include [`.Distinct()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netcore-3.1):

```
List<int> RoomIds = classRooms
    .Where(x => x.Teacher == "Mr.Taylor")
    .Select(x => x.RoomId)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```